# How to solve Error: Metadata version mismatch for module found version 4, expected 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

During the production build in my Ionic application I have this error:

```
Error: Metadata version mismatch for module C:/Users/p/Desktop/p/trunk/p/Work/node_modules/ionic2-calendar/calendar.module.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
```

This is my `package.json`, does it look good?

```
    {
  "name": "ggggg",
  "author": "Chris",
  "homepage": "none",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.9.2",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "3.9.2",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^3.9.2",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "3.9.2",
    "@ionic-native/network": "3.9.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.9.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.9.2",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.12.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.0",
    "cordova-android": "6.2.3",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "4.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-event": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.1.0",
    "crypto-js": "3.1.9-1",
    "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification": "~0.8.5",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ionic": "^3.12.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "2.2.1",
    "ionic2-calendar": "^0.4.4",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "patternomaly": "^1.3.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.10",
    "typescript": "2.3.2"
  },
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "Gme",
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "browser",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

What can be the reason? I know it is about versioning but still I can't find the solution to this.

I have tried downgrading to an older version of ionic, from 4 to 3. But it doesn't help.

Comment: Did you try running `npm i` ?

Comment: @trichetriche yes of course

Comment: Then maybe try downgrading `"ionic2-calendar": "^0.4.4"`

Comment: https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar/issues/251

Answer (score 0):

The solution for was just to update ng-bootstrap to version beta.6.
Please try this command

npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.6 --save